# Call other function from Main()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, program-entry-point

i have one function that will update my UI

```
public void Checking()
{
    // Do Something 
}
```

I want to call these function Upon opening the program : Which i believe i should call it in main:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Checking(); 
}
```

But here the I'm getting an error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

P.S: im using WPF...
Any solution for this?

Comment: See the inner exception and details of the exception, they might give you a hint

Comment: can u please try to call Checking() in Form_Load

Comment: can you put this in window load?

Comment: Im using WPF so no form loading here....

Comment: I think they're referring to the `Loaded` event. If you comment out the `Checking` call, does the exception go away?

Comment: ofcourse without calling Checking at main i have no problem and program Run as Usual, However i need to Update My UI once opening the window so i need to call Checking() in Main...

Comment: @PublicAffair Understood, I just wanted to make sure I was understanding the problem correctly and that everything worked until the method call was added. It seems likely that the logic in your `Checking` method is actually throwing an exception. Can you confirm?

Comment: MainWindow is a constructor and I dont think updating UI in constructor is a good idea. Can u please check calling the method in Loaded event?

Comment: It Could be but the function its given by other Department i cant make any changes, im quiet new in WPF so im not sure how to solve this

Comment: @PublicAffair Perhaps surround the call in a `Try-Catch` and put a breakpoint in the `Catch` to see if you hit anything.

Comment: @JasonTyler oh ok .. i ty and catch these is my catch Error ([System.NullReferenceException] = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: What that is telling you is that something that your Checking Function is needing is has not been initialized yet. We are not asking you to change your Checking Method just try moving its call to your Windows Loaded Event, that will let you know if you are calling it to soon. You could also try putting a breakpoint on the call to your Checking method and step into it to see exactly what object is not instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor setup the Windows Loaded event and call your Checking() method from there. The UI is not ready for interaction in the contructor, not until the XAML has been completely loaded. WPF has an event to let you know this has happened (the Loaded event).

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Checking(); 
}
```

If you still get errors then you will need to look at your inner exception, you should be told what is causing the error. You could also step through the Checking() method to see what line the error happens on.

[edit] Here are some additional resources on the Loaded event and the order of events in a WPF page lifecycle:

[MSDN: FrameworkElement.Loaded Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)
[Control Lifecycle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/10/11/control-lifecycle.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function the way you are using. But something inside the Checking() might need your Panel (or something) to be loaded.

You can create an event handler that is fired once your panel gets loaded. And then you can call your checking() function from there.

```
<StackPanel Loaded="myStackPanelLoaded" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens to me.

In WPF when `Exception` occurs in the constructor of the form this message is thrown. so try  calling the `Checking()` function in the `FormLoad` event handler of the `MainForm`. This way you will see what kind of `Exception` you have in your program.